# Node JS - Should i do "return cb(..)" or first cb(..) and then return?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-management, callback

This may be a dumb question but I just want to know the implications on doing this:

Whenever I get an error or I want to finish some function flow I have instructions such as:

```
if(err) {
    cb(err);   // or for example res.json({...});
    return;
}
```

However I've seen some codes with the following format:

```
if(err) {
    return cb(err);
}
```

Are there any memory or other kind of risks on doing that? Carrying on the function value over all the functions?

Which is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the host function and the caller is not expecting a return value, then either of your two choices will execute identically.  The second one:

```
return cb(err);
```

is often done purely for short-hand reasons (putting the return on the one line).  Personally, I don't like this shorthand because when one reads this code, it implies that `cb()` is returning a value that you want to return from the host function, but that isn't the case at all.

So, I prefer:

```
if(err) {
    cb(err);   // or for example res.json({...});
    return;
}
```

or even sometimes:

```
if(err) {
    cb(err);   // or for example res.json({...});
} else {
    // other code here
}
```

Because both of these make it a lot clearer that there is no return value intended from the host function or from the callback.  But, this my opinion about code clarity - there is no material difference in execution.

> Are there any memory or other kind of risks on doing that? Carrying on the function value over all the functions?

A plain `return` statement or a function that just ends without any `return` statement returns `undefined`.  If the `cb()` returns `undefined, then`return cb()`also returns`undefined` from the host function.  So, there should be no difference in return value there either.  With no difference in return value, there should be no difference in memory usage.

The `return cb()` code does allow the callback to return a value that also becomes the return value of the host function. If that's what you want, then you would have to code it this way, but that is typically not what you're intending so using `return cb()` allows the caller to perhaps use the callback return value in a way you don't intend which you might inadvertently break in the future because it wasn't an intended feature.

Comment: `return cb(...)` makes it a tail call, which could theoretically use less stack space than `cb(...); return`, but I'm unsure whether V8 actually applies this optimization in any circumstance.

Comment: @icktoofay - Nor is it clear that even if it was treated as a tail call would it make a difference of any consequence here.  Tail call recursion is an interesting optimization, this one (which is not recursion), not so much.